# Remove the element at the index given

Tags: java

fI have to remove an element with given index in the parameter of method: `void remove(int index)`. I don't know how to iterate through object and remove element. Pls help :)

Write a method void remove(int index) that removes the element at the index given as
parameter. Make sure the index is valid. Don’t forget to “shift” the other elements in the
array so you don’t end up with an array with “holes”.

The code I wrote look like this :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class MyArray<E>{
    public void remove(int index){
        for(int i =0 ; i < objects.length;i++)
    }

    
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add an actual question. Is there a problem? Paste either the compiler error, or the runtime error, or the result you get vs. the result you wanted.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: This is  visibly [java] code, not [c], so I fixed the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a homework exercise (if it is not, what are you trying to accomplish? Java has `java.util.ArrayList` which is this exact idea, implemented properly, just use that), so you should presumably ask your teacher for help, they get paid for it.

I'll give you a hint: There is no easy option here. To fix this stuff (and to debug code!) first you need to get a handle on how it works. This is best done by taking some simple but realistic input and sketching out what your code should be doing.

For example, let's say we have a MyArray instance. With nothing yet, and a capacity of 5. What should `size` be (-1 is suspect; it's got 0 elements in it, not -1). What should `maxcapacity` be? What should the array slots look like?

Presumably the answers are: `0`, `5`, and `[null, null, null, null, null]`.

Next you add elements `a`, `c`, `f`, and `h`.

What should the answers be now? Presumably, `4`, `5`, `["a", "c", "f", "h", null]`.

Now, remove "c". What should it be now?

Write that down and then figure out what code to write that make that happen. HINT: It will involve a loop or System.arraycopy, because "f" and "h" aren't going to just move themselves one position to the left!